# Edit A CommandParameters Bound Variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a rectangle whose background colour is bound to a variable. When I click the rectangle I want to bring up a colour picker such that the user can change the colour of the rectangle.

The problem I have is when I change `o` it doesn't change `WorkflowModel.BackgroundColour` as I would expect, it only changes `o`

Any idea how I can achieve this or if there is some way I can pass a `ref` of `WorkflowModel.BackgroundColour` and edit it that way.

XAML:

```
<Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Width="25">
    <Rectangle.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding WorkflowModel.BackgroundColour}"                                       
                        Command="{Binding ChangeColorCommand}"/>
    </Rectangle.InputBindings>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding WorkflowModel.BackgroundColour}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Command:

```
private void ChangeColorCommandExecute(object o)
{
    Views.DialogViews.ColorPickerDialog cpd = new Views.DialogViews.ColorPickerDialog((Color)o);
    cpd.ShowDialog();

    if(cpd.DialogResult == Views.DialogViews.ColorPickerDialog.DialogResults.Ok)
    {
        o = cpd.SelectedColor;
    }
}

public ICommand ChangeColorCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(o => ChangeColorCommandExecute(o)); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CommandParameter to bind to the WorkflowModel. Then in the `ChangeColorCommandExecute` cast the `object o` to a WorkflowModel and use the `BackgroundColour` property.

If it is not appropriate to have your command handler take a dependency on the `WorkflowModel` wrap your colour in its own `ColourViewModel` and bind the command parameter to the `ColourViewModel`

```
public class ColourViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Color _colour;
  public Color Colour 
  {
    get { return _colour; }
    set
    {
      _colour = value;
      // raise change notification
    }
  }
}

private void ChangeColorCommandExecute(object o)
{
    ColourViewModel cvm = o as ColourViewModel;
    if (cvm != null)
    {
       Views.DialogViews.ColorPickerDialog cpd = new Views.DialogViews.ColorPickerDialog(cvm.Colour);
      cpd.ShowDialog();

      if(cpd.DialogResult == Views.DialogViews.ColorPickerDialog.DialogResults.Ok)
      {
        cvm.Colour = cpd.SelectedColor;
      }
    }
}
```